# Anyone know what cause this crash:"[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector"?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

Recently I use NSTextTable draw table. I want change some attribute of selected block,so save selected paragraphs into dictionary. After I copy the block of paragraph, once I call method [NSTextTableBlock setBorderColor:], raise an error:

```
-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000002442c0
```

I try many times, finally found a phenomenon, which is if I don't copy block, setBorderColor: is OK.
Anyone know relation of [NSTextTableBlock copy] and this error, why [NSTextTableBlock setBorderColor:] cause this error? I'm quite confuse about this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know NSArray and NSMutableArray, but the question is I didn't use any NSArray to save my instance value, I just copy a NSTextTableBlock from dictionary!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSArray` does not have the selector `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` (so you can't call it). You are actually trying to modify an [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) which can not be modified like that. You probably want [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/) instead. You can create an `NSMutableArray` from an `NSArray`, call your method and then replace your reference to the original array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
[mutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:object];
array = mutableArray;//now the array has been "updated"
```

Comment: The question is I didn't use any NSArray to save my instance value, I just copy a NSTextTableBlock from dictionary. Thank you all the same.